# Code Memory Utilisation Increasing Rapidly - Spring Boot

Tags: java, performance, spring-boot, memory-leaks, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring Boot 2.3.0 with openjdk:8u252-jre-slim and java 14 also to build my container.

I ran **JProfiler** on my local as well and could see in Java 14 there was periodic GC but in Java 8 GC was **not** happening at all.

Within 2 hours I can see the RAM utilisation getting **increased by 20 MB**. I have deployed my service on AKS.

**AKS Pod Memory Consumption - 24 Hours 100 MB Increased!!**
[image: AKS Pod Memory Consumption - 24 Hours 100 MB Increased!!]

My Code snippet -

```
@Component
public class CronScheduler {

@Value("${url1}")
private String url1;

@Value("${url2}")
private String url2;

@Value("${username}")
private String username;

@Value("${password}")
private String password;

private RestTemplate restTemplate;

private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CronScheduler.class);

@Autowired
public CronScheduler(RestTemplate restTemplate, JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}

@Scheduled(cron = "${polling-time-1}")
public void schedulePollingEndpoint1() {

    String message = restTemplate.getForObject(url1, String.class);

    logger.info(message);

}

@Scheduled(cron = "${polling-time-2}")
public void schedulePollingEndpoint12() {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setBasicAuth(username, password);
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

    ResponseEntity<Result> response = null;
    try {
        response = restTemplate.exchange(new URI(url2), HttpMethod.GET, request, Result.class);

        int[][] updateResult = batchUpdate(response.getBody().getResult());

        logger.info("Updated Rows - " + Arrays.deepToString(updateResult));
    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public int[][] batchUpdate(List<Entity> myList) {

    ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter<Entity> pss = (ps, entity) -> {
        ps.setString(1, entity.getState());
        ps.setLong(2, Long.parseLong(entity.getUpdatedAt()));
        ps.setString(3, entity.getId());
    };

    return jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
            "update myTable set state = ? , updated_at = ? where  id = ?", myList,
            myList.size(), pss);

}
```

}

Additionally I have code which **converts date to epoch when we fetch the list** in pollingURl2 Method -

```
 public void setSys_updated_on(String sys_updated_on) throws ParseException {
    Long millis = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse(sys_updated_on).getTime();
    this.sys_updated_on = millis.toString().substring(0, 10);
}
```

Can someone guide in direction from where shall I start to look at?

Comment: Make a heapdump and analyze it with a tool like the eclipse memory analyzer?

Comment: any blog or links to follow...

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-capture-java-heap-dumps-7-options